# XNA game starts drawing off screen on laptop

Tags: c#, xna, window

I currently have my XNA PC game running in a borderless windowed mode which has worked well until recently on my new laptop. It seems to start drawing a few hundred pixels off the screen to the top left. This leaves a gap at the bottom of the screen and on the right where you can see the desktop below the game. All the mouse coords are accurate to where you should have to mouse over and click on things even though it's just not drawing in the right place.

My older laptop it drew correctly but this new one I just got it seems to be off somehow. I am using David Amador's Resolution class to set up a virtual resolution via:

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
Resolution.Init(ref graphics);

control = Control.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
Resolution.SetVirtualResolution(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width, GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height);
Resolution.SetResolution(GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width, GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height, false);
```

I set fullscreen to false and then once I create the game screen I do the following to set it to borderless:

```
Form gameForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(curGame.Window.Handle);
gameForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

I tried doing "gameForm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);" to try and force set it to start drawing at (0,0) but with my current set up that doesn't seem to do anything because I can set it to (150, 150) and it won't start drawing there. Here is a screenshot from my laptop that shows how it's moved the window and cut off the left and top side exposing the desktop:

[image: off position]

Does anyone have any idea why it could be happening now on my new laptop when it hasn't happened on my desktop or old laptop ever before?

Comment: hm seems like it has something to do with the borderless. Turning it off fixes it and full screen works fine.

Comment: That's odd, I add `gameForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` and it now starts in the right place but it runs way off the bottom and right side of the screen.